# How do I disable auto-completion for Eclipse using Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

The auto-completion in Eclipse is extremely irritating.  I feel like I've searched everything, but I cannot find where to disable auto-completion.  Does anyone know how I can disable it?  Thanks.

Comment: You can disable it, but a better option for you may be to increase the time before the content assist presents a popup box. By default I believe it's like 50ms, which is about instant. You can push it to 2000-3000ms so that it only comes if you've come to a dead stop.

Answer (score 2):

- **`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist.`**.
- **`Uncheck  "*Insert single proposals automatically*" -> Apply -> Ok.`**

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Downvoter: Please consider adding a comment what went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the settings for auto-completion can be found under...

Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist